# I need to stop thread when progress bar reaches 0 in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need stop thread and handler when my progress bar reaches 0 from 100 when thread runs the progress bar reaches but the progressStatus value going in negative please help me to stop thread after progress bar reaches 0

```
 new Thread(runn =new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

         while (progressStatus <= 100) {
             progressStatus += doWork();
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             // Update the progress bar
             handler.post(runn1=new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     bar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                     i=-1;                                                  
                     if(bar.getProgress()==0)
                     {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runn); 
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runn1);
                         System.out.println("Reached");
                      congrats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         restart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                         rightbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         wrongbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                     }
                 }
             });



         }



     }
     private int doWork() {

         return i;
      }

     }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

your program is not **thread safe**, you actually reading and writing a variable `(progressStatus)` from two different threads, you must avoid doing that or if you want to do that you must use `synchronized` block. In order to solve your problem you can do this way:

```
Thread t;
progressStatus = 100;
t =  new Thread(runn =new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

         while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 return;
             }
             // Update the progress bar
             handler.post(runn1=new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     bar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                     progressStatus=progressStatus-1;                                                  
                     if(bar.getProgress()==0)
                     {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runn); 
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runn1);
                        System.out.println("Reached");
                        congrats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        restart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                        rightbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        wrongbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        t.interrupt();

                     }
                 }
             });
```

another way that i recommend you is using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with the function `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)`. something like:

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor myTimer = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

                    @Override    
                    public void run() {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                            }
                       });  


                    }   
            }

}, 0,10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and in order to close it use `myTimer.shutdownNow();`